# OSX: colors are strange for only one user

Tags: macos

On my iMac I have two users. One for my wife one for me. When I login are colors are fine, just like on my others computers. When logging in with the other account you can hardly see any gradient, all colors are blunt and the contrast is strange. All fonts seem to bleed or are hardly readable. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot? I'm interested in seeing if the bad colors show up in the screenshot if you view the png as the other user.

Comment: Good point! The screenshot wasn't affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things spring to mind immediately: in the **Universal Access** system preference (Apple Menu>System Preferences…) there is a setting for enhancing the contrast, check that the slider is on "Normal".

Otherwise go to the **Display** system preference and look at the Color tab. There are various color profiles there, see if the profile for you wife is the same as yours.

Comment: Thanks! That did the job! It was the contrast setting in the Universal Access.